# Passing a 2D array to a subroutine expecting a 3D array

Tags: arrays, fortran

I need to use a subroutine that expects 3D array as input, but I am dealing with a special case where the third dimension is not required. This subroutine gets called by another one that deals with this special case.

```
subroutine my_special_case (array)
  real, dimension(:,:)   :: array
  ! some code
  call foo (array)
end subroutine

subroutine foo (array)
  real, dimension(:,:,:) :: array
  ! some code
end subroutine
```

I could probably just create an allocatable 3D array where to store the values in the 2D one like this

```
subroutine my_special_case (array)
  real, dimension(:,:)                :: array
  real, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: pass
  ! some code
  allocate( pass( size(array,1), size(array,2), 1) )
  pass(:,:,1) = array(:,:)
  call foo (pass)
end subroutine
```

but it just feels wasteful and slow to copy the whole array in the second one just to adapt the rank. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to use pointer remapping

```
subroutine my_special_case (array)
  real, dimension(:,:), target   :: array
  real, dimension(:,:,:), pointer :: ptr
  ptr(1:size(array,1), 1:size(array,2), 1:1) => array
  ! some code
  call foo (ptr)
end subroutine

subroutine foo (array)
  real, dimension(:,:,:) :: array
  ! some code
end subroutine
```

Or you could make foo to accept an explicit size array `dimension(nx,ny)` or an assumed-size array `dimension(nx,*)` and just use traditional  sequence association.

Comment: Thanks! This is surely a lot better. However it complains that "Rank remapping target must be rank 1 or simply contiguous". I think that simply adding `real, dimension(:,:), contiguous, target   :: array` should work fine.

Comment: @Sine Yes. Be aware that if the array passed to the subroutine is not contiguous, a copy will be made. More recent versions of gfortran may do the copy more often than you would expect, when you forget `contiguous` somewhere in the chain. Unfortunatell we cannot see the calling code so cannot say more. Also be aware that the other alternatives would also make a copy for a non-contiguous array.